nftables equivalent for iptables condition module
The iptables condition module allows you to make a rule match depending on whether the contents of a file are 0 or 1.
iptables -A INPUT -m condition --condition enable-my-foo-rule 

This will accept all ÌNPUT traffic if the contents of /proc/net/ipt_condition/filename are 1
Is there an equivalent in the nftables world?

can you please provide an example line of iptables command.

I added an example

are you trying to switch from iptables to nftables on the same machine ? if no, the kernel module xt_condition or ipt_condition is required to have the match "condition" in iptables. Do you have such module loaded on the kernel were you trying to setup nftables rules ?

Yes, I have xt_condition. I'm trying to move from iptables to nftables. I'm looking for an equivalent way to do this using nftables syntax

iptables-translate -A INPUT -m condition --condition enable-my-foo-rule
nft -A INPUT -m condition --condition enable-my-foo-rule           according to iptables-translate  the syntax should be the same. Do you have an error ?

iptables-translate -A INPUT -m condition --condition enable-my-foo-rule nft -A INPUT -m condition --condition enable-my-foo-rule gives me Bad argument nft'`
iptables-translate -A INPUT -m condition --condition enable-my-foo-rule -m condition --condition enable-my-foo-rule gives me nft # -A INPUT -m condition --condition enable-my-foo-rule -m condition --condition enable-my-foo-rule, which to my understanding means that it's not supported.
What do you get?
